# Math issue causing errors with percentages

Tags: java, processing

I'm creating an application to calculate class scores, and then based on scores, output a letter grade.

In summary, I'm not the greatest at math, I'm having trouble identifying where my math error is located in the code, and the console is splitting out excessive percentage values because of it.

Here is what the console is outputting:

```
My quiz percentage is 83.33333
my lab percentage is 72.916664
My Mid-Term percentage is 196.72131
my End-Term Percentage is 200.72131
My final percentage grade is 115.35263
Calculation error: possible percentage values between 1%-100%. Check your math and try again.
```

(The last line is just an if statement to show that there is a calculation error. When done correctly, it should output a letter grade as handled by the other if statements.)

Below is my code:

```
//Quiz scores
float q1=20, q2=19, q3=14, q4=17, actualQuizPoints=70, actualPoints=80, totalMidTermPoints=120, actualMidTermPoints=61; 

//Lab scores
float l1=20, l2=19, l3=14, l4=17;


void setup() {
  noLoop();
  size(100,100);
  }

void draw() {  
  float totalQuizPoints=Addition(q1, q2, q3, q4);
  float quizPercentage = Percentage(totalQuizPoints, actualQuizPoints);
  float totalLabPoints =Addition(l1, l2, l3, l4);
  float labPercentage=Percentage(totalLabPoints, actualPoints);
  float midTermPercentage=Percentage(totalMidTermPoints, actualMidTermPoints);
  float endTermPercentage=midTermPercentage+4;
  float finalPercentage=Addition(quizPercentage, labPercentage, midTermPercentage, endTermPercentage)/4;
  println("My quiz percentage is " + quizPercentage);
  println("my lab percentage is " + labPercentage);
  println("My Mid-Term percentage is " + midTermPercentage);
  println("my End-Term Percentage is " + endTermPercentage);
  println("My final percentage grade is " + finalPercentage);

  if (finalPercentage  <60) {
  println ("My final letter grade is F.");
      }


  if (finalPercentage  >=60 & finalPercentage <70) {
  println ("My final letter grade is D.");
      }

  if (finalPercentage  >=70 & finalPercentage <80) {
  println ("My final letter grade is C.");
      }

  if (finalPercentage  >=80 & finalPercentage <90) {
  println ("My final letter grade is B.");
      }

  if (finalPercentage  >=90 & finalPercentage <=100) {
  println ("My final letter grade is A.");
      }


  if (finalPercentage  >100) {
  println ("Calculation error: possible percentage values between 1%-100%. Check your math and try again.");
      }

   }

float Addition(Float n1, float n2, float n3, float n4) {
  float total=(n1+n2+n3+n4)/120*100;
  return total;
   }

float Percentage(float totalpoints, float actualpoints) {
  float percentageIs=(totalpoints/actualpoints)*100;
  return percentageIs;
   }
```

Comment: Why is total divided ?  total=(n1+n2+n3+n4)/120*100;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not being consistent with how you're using the terms `total` and `actual`.

For the quiz points and lab points, you're using `total` to mean the sum of all earned points, and `actual` to mean the points that could have been earned.

For the midterm, endterm, and final points, you switch those around.

You need to modify your code so that you're consistent with the parameters you're passing into the `percentage()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Don't care so much for everyone else thinks, but I just want to try answer for fun. Didn't understand all your code. But I have posted my whole code with my "findings" at the bottom.

My commenting is optional

At least the code at the bottom gives actual percentages within 0-100% if you compile :)

result:

```
My quiz percentage is 87.5
my lab percentage is 87.5
My Mid-Term percentage is 50.833332
my End-Term Percentage is 54.833332
My final percentage grade is 70.166664
My final letter grade is C.
```

Not so sure what this code was:

```
void setup() {
    noLoop();
    size(100,100);
}
```

I mainly changed your addition method to actually adding 4 numbers:

```
float Addition(Float n1, float n2, float n3, float n4) {
  float total=(n1+n2+n3+n4);
  return total;
   }
```

And I think I changed around some of the parameters f. instance:

```
float quizPercentage = Percentage(totalQuizPoints, actualQuizPoints);
```

To actualPoints. Or else it would calculate 70 / 70 *100. Wich is 100

I also switched the parameters with eachother:

```
  float midTermPercentage=Percentage(totalMidTermPoints, actualMidTermPoints);
```

I'm not so sure what this means but i left it:

```
 float endTermPercentage=midTermPercentage+4;
```

Whole code:

```
class Grading{
//Quiz scores
float q1=20, q2=19, q3=14, q4=17, actualQuizPoints=70, actualPoints=80, totalMidTermPoints=120, actualMidTermPoints=61; 

//Lab scores
float l1=20, l2=19, l3=14, l4=17;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Grading g=new Grading();
        g.draw();
    }




void draw() {  
  float totalQuizPoints=Addition(q1, q2, q3, q4);
  float quizPercentage = Percentage(totalQuizPoints, actualPoints);
  float totalLabPoints =Addition(l1, l2, l3, l4);
  float labPercentage=Percentage(totalLabPoints, actualPoints);
  float midTermPercentage=Percentage(actualMidTermPoints, totalMidTermPoints);
  float endTermPercentage=midTermPercentage+4;
  float finalPercentage=Addition(quizPercentage, labPercentage, midTermPercentage, endTermPercentage)/4;
  System.out.println("My quiz percentage is " + quizPercentage);
  System.out.println("my lab percentage is " + labPercentage);
  System.out.println("My Mid-Term percentage is " + midTermPercentage);
  System.out.println("my End-Term Percentage is " + endTermPercentage);
  System.out.println("My final percentage grade is " + finalPercentage);

  if (finalPercentage  <60) {
  System.out.println ("My final letter grade is F.");
      }


  if (finalPercentage  >=60 & finalPercentage <70) {
  System.out.println ("My final letter grade is D.");
      }

  if (finalPercentage  >=70 & finalPercentage <80) {
  System.out.println ("My final letter grade is C.");
      }

  if (finalPercentage  >=80 & finalPercentage <90) {
  System.out.println ("My final letter grade is B.");
      }

  if (finalPercentage  >=90 & finalPercentage <=100) {
  System.out.println ("My final letter grade is A.");
      }


  if (finalPercentage  >100) {
  System.out.println ("Calculation error: possible percentage values between 1%-100%. Check your math and try again.");
      }

   }

float Addition(Float n1, float n2, float n3, float n4) {
  float total=(n1+n2+n3+n4);
  return total;
   }

float Percentage(float totalpoints, float actualpoints) {

  float percentageIs=(totalpoints/actualpoints)*100;
  return percentageIs;
   }
}
```